# Change HUE of a Bitmap but retain background color?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have been experimenting with the `Change HUE/Saturation` example found on the EFG website: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/Color.htm

[image]

I want to use the techniques found in that example to change the color values of some bitmaps (to be used on a TImage). There is one problem I am facing, and that is with TImages that have transparent bitmaps; I don't want the background color to change its HUE but rather just the actual image data.

Take this sample image we can work with (though any image with transparency can be used):

[image]

- Download the `Change HUE/Saturation` demo from the link at the top.
- Now Load the button image above into the ImageOriginal.
- Set the Delta Saturation to 1.
- Run the Project.

Some output results:

[image] [image]

What I would like to happen here is keep the original background color (defined by the bottom left most pixel) and only adjust the hue for the rest of the image. So, the output results would actually look like this (edited in Paint.NET):

[image] [image]

Allow me to use another sample image to test with that contains more image data:

[image]

As before with the first image sample, the results could be something like:

[image] [image]

When the results I desire should be like so:

[image] [image]

One idea I had was after the HUE change, replace the bottom left most color with the color from the original, but I am not sure if this is the correct approach or not, and even if it is I am not sure how to replace color X for another color. (Graphics and Math is beyond me).

For example, if I drew two blue color circles on Mickey's ear (the blue been the original transparent color from bottom left most pixel) and also colored his eyes:

[image]

Changing the HUE again may look like:

[image]

when in fact it should like this:

[image]

Simply put I would like to change the HUE of an image whether it be by the methods used from the EFG demo or another solution. The transparent color as defined by the bottom most left pixel should not be changed when the HUE is changed, this should remain the same as demonstrated in the sample images.

How can I change the HUE of a bitmap whilst retaining the background color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you refer walks all pixels on the image to change hue/saturation. You can modify the code so that it does not interfere if a pixel has a specific color:

```
PROCEDURE TFormChangeHS.UpdateBitmap;
    ..
    S              :  TReal;
    V              :  TReal;

    FixColor: TRGBTriple;                            // New variable
BEGIN
  DeltaSaturation := SpinEditDeltaSaturation.Value;
  NewHue := TrackBarHue.Position;

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  TRY
    Bitmap.Width  := ImageOriginal.Width;
    Bitmap.Height := ImageOriginal.Height;
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := ImageOriginal.Picture.Bitmap.PixelFormat;
    ASSERT(Bitmap.PixelFormat = pf24bit);

    // save bottom left color
    FixColor := PRGBTripleArray(
                  ImageOriginal.Picture.Bitmap.ScanLine[Bitmap.Height - 1])^[0];
    //--

    FOR j := 0 TO Bitmap.Height-1 DO
    BEGIN
      RowIn  := ImageOriginal.Picture.Bitmap.Scanline[j];
      RowOut := Bitmap.Scanline[j];
      FOR i := 0 TO Bitmap.Width-1 DO
      BEGIN
        WITH RowIn[i] DO
        BEGIN

          // copy the color to target and continue with next iteration
          if (RowIn[i].rgbtBlue = FixColor.rgbtBlue) and
              (RowIn[i].rgbtGreen = FixColor.rgbtGreen) and
              (RowIn[i].rgbtRed = FixColor.rgbtRed) then begin
            RowOut[i] := FixColor;
            Continue;
          end;
          //--

          // convert pixel coordinates to HSV
          RGBtoHSV(rgbtRed, rgbtGreen, rgbtBlue, H, S, V);
        END;
        ..
        ..
```

Output:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Excellent Sertac that works as I had hoped. Could you explain this line though please: `FixColor := PRGBTripleArray(
                  ImageOriginal.Picture.Bitmap.ScanLine[Bitmap.Height - 1])^[0];` Is this the equivalent to using Pixels[] but it is faster? I am not sure what the ^[0] bit is doing.

Comment: @Blobby - You can in fact delete the `^`, it's not needed (what the PRGBTripleArray points to, but the compiler can resolve it without the '^'), the left part is a TRGBTripleArray, hence [0] is the first element of the array. The speed is not important since we're reading only one pixel, you can very well use Pixels instead.

Comment: Great thanks for clearing that up. I think I understand the other code aswell - `if (RowIn[i].rgbtBlue = FixColor.rgbtBlue) and`.. is this checking the color of each pixel in the RGB channel, and if each of the RGB component equals to FixColor you convert it to the FixColor?

Comment: @Blobby - Yep, if each of the RGB components equals to that of FixColor, put that color to the same pixel of the target bitmap and continue with the next iteration of the 'for' loop.

Comment: Looks so simple when you see it put in front of you! It's getting the logical thinking which keeps holding me back, let's just say problem solving is not a strong point for me! Thanks for clarifying your answer too it really helps if I understand at least some of it.

Comment: @Blobby - Just give yourself some time. ;)

Comment: I keep saying that to myself but I end up spending too long trying to solve a problem and thinking too hard which results in confusion and headaches a lot of the time. Thanks for the encouragement and tips though :)

Comment: You have the first step in problem solving down to a fine art: asking a good question. I am sure that by asking the question as well as you did here, you were already halfway on your way to the answer yourself. Just keep practicing asking well formulated questions and you'll get there. The answer was right there in your question... you just need some more practice in spotting it.

Comment: @MarjanVenema thanks for the encouragement, I think the hardest part of any programming skill is the problem solving and as you say I just need more practice at spotting and figuring out how to solve such problems. It is not always so easy though, the answer could be staring me in the face and I might not even see it.

Comment: When that happens: take a break. Doing something else often is the best problem solving / answer spotting activity around.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you can for example:

First, you have to determine what is the background... (probably picking the color of a specific pixel like delphi does...)

Then, with this background color, you can create a mask based on this color...

You duplicate the image... apply the hue...

You merge your 2 bitmaps using the mask...

Comment: sounds like a good idea, I have never worked with masks before however.

Comment: check them.. they can be very useful ;o) the hardest part is maybe, to **efficiently** create the mask with **compressed** jpeg

Comment: As it is Sertac's answer works perfectly, but thanks to your answer I think I may look further into masks, I have an idea what they are but I will definitely get some information on them :)